# Error building app Cordova marketing Cloud sdk

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, cordova, react

I have an app using React Js and Cordova, I need to integrate it with [[Marketing Cloud SDK]](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/MC-Cordova-Plugin), I followed the instruction that the plugin mentions, but it throws me an error when compiling The error it throws is the following.

```
/home/USER/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/20613ec3cd3b4199/jetified-marketingcloudsdk-7.3.1/res/values/values.xml:161:5-169:13: AAPT: error: style attribute 'attr/layout_constraintWidth_max (aka com.mobile:attr/layout_constraintWidth_max)' not found.
 
 /home/USER/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/20613ec3cd3b4199/jetified-marketingcloudsdk-7.3.1/res/values/values.xml:194:5-204:13: AAPT: error: style attribute 'attr/layout_constraintWidth_max (aka com.mobile:attr/layout_constraintWidth_max)' not found.
 
 /home/USER/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/20613ec3cd3b4199/jetified-marketingcloudsdk-7.3.1/res/values/values.xml:213:5-221:13: AAPT: error: style attribute 'attr/layout_constraintWidth_max (aka com.mobile:attr/layout_constraintWidth_max)' not found.
 
 /home/USER/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/20613ec3cd3b4199/jetified-marketingcloudsdk-7.3.1/res/values/values.xml:238:5-241:13: AAPT: error: style attribute 'attr/layout_constraintDimensionRatio (aka com.mobile:attr/layout_constraintDimensionRatio)' not found.
 
 /home/USER/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/20613ec3cd3b4199/jetified-marketingcloudsdk-7.3.1/res/values/values.xml:250:5-260:13: AAPT: error: style attribute 'attr/layout_constraintWidth_max (aka com.mobile:attr/layout_constraintWidth_max)' not found.
```

The file that is generated in the compilation (values.xml) is the attribute layout_constraintWidth_max

I already tried, removing cache from gradle and npm, removing the platforms, plugin, node_modules directories and it follows the same

```
npm 6.14.8
nodejs v10.19.0
cordova 10.0.0
android@9.0.0
cordova-plugin-marketingcloudsdk:^7.3.0
```

Any idea on how i can get this to work? Thanks.

Regards.